# Segue not being executed in viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on my first iOS app.

There is a viewController that checks if the user has already signed in.

```
print("Usuario actual logeado:",logeado_actual ?? "ninguno")

        if (logeado_actual == "OK"){
             print("logeado:")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sinlogear", sender: nil)
        }
```

The print output is

```
Usuario actual logeado: OK
logeado:
```

that means that the segue should be executed, but it doesn't.

The segue exists and the Identifier is `sinlogear`

Is there anything missing or not valid in my code?

[image]

EDIT

Full code:

```
import Alamofire

import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var btnAcceder: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var btnContinuar: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var btnRegistro: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnOlvidar: UIButton!
    //Defined a constant that holds the URL for our web service
    let URL_USER_REGISTER = "https://.../android_api/login.php"

    struct Usuario: Codable {
        var id: Int
        var activacion: Int
        var autorizado: Int
        var cif: String
        var correo: String
        var cuenta: String
        var direccion: String
        var empresa: String
        var facebook_id: String
        var foto_usuario: String
        var instagram_id: String
        var num_estrellas: Int
        var tel: String
        var token_firebase: String
        var twitter_id: String
        var usuario: String
        var nombre: String
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var txtLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!


    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard




    @IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        print("login pulsado")

        //creating parameters for the post request
        let parameters: Parameters=[
            "email":txtEmail.text!,
            "password":txtPassword.text!
        ]

        print(txtEmail.text!)

         self.txtLabel.text = ""

        //Sending http post request
            Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
            {
                response in
                //printing response
                print(response)

                //getting the json value from the server
                if let resultado = response.result.value {

                    //converting it as NSDictionary
                    let jsonData = resultado as! NSDictionary


                    let id = jsonData.value(forKey:"id") as! NSNumber?
                    let estado = jsonData.value(forKey: "error") as! NSNumber?

                    if estado == 0 {
                    print("login:","OK")
                         self.txtLabel.text = "Datos correctos"
                        print("error:",estado!)
                                          print("id user:",id!)

                        if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                            //usuario
                            do {
                                guard let user = json["user"] as? [String: Any],
                                      let usuario = user["usuario"] as? String
                                    else {

                                      print("Failed to parse JSON")
                                      return
                                }

                                self.defaults.set(usuario, forKey: "usuario")
                                self.defaults.set("OK", forKey: "logeado")
                                print(usuario)

                        }
                            //nombre
                                do {
                                    guard let user = json["user"] as? [String: Any],
                                          let nombre = user["nombre"] as? String
                                        else {

                                          print("Failed to parse JSON")
                                          return
                                    }

                                    self.defaults.set(nombre, forKey: "nombre")

                                    print(nombre)

                            }
                            //imageb
                                do {
                                    guard let user = json["user"] as? [String: Any],
                                          let foto_usuario = user["foto_usuario"] as? String
                                        else {

                                          print("Failed to parse JSON")
                                          return
                                    }
                                    self.defaults.set(foto_usuario, forKey: "foto_usuario")

                                    print(foto_usuario)

                            }
                            //correo
                           do {
                               guard let user = json["user"] as? [String: Any],
                                     let correo_usuario = user["correo"] as? String
                                   else {

                                     print("Failed to parse JSON")
                                     return
                               }
                               self.defaults.set(correo_usuario, forKey: "correo")


                               print(correo_usuario)
                       }

                        }




                    }
                    else {
                    print("login:","NO OK")

                        self.txtLabel.text = "Datos incorrectos"

                    }




                }
            }

        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            let usuario_actual = self.defaults.string(forKey: "usuario")
            let nombre_usuario_actual = self.defaults.string(forKey: "nombre")
            let foto_usuario_actual = self.defaults.string(forKey: "foto_usuario")
        let correo_usuario_actual = self.defaults.string(forKey: "correo")
        let logeado_actual = self.defaults.string(forKey: "logeado")

        print("Usuario actual:",usuario_actual ?? "ninguno")
        print("Usuario actual nombre:",nombre_usuario_actual ?? "ninguno")
        print("Usuario actual foto:",foto_usuario_actual ?? "ninguno")
         print("Usuario actual correo:",correo_usuario_actual ?? "ninguno")
        print("Usuario actual logeado:",logeado_actual ?? "ninguno")

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "misegue", sender: self)

        if (logeado_actual == "OK"){
             print("logeado:")

        }


        //redondear botones


        btnAcceder.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        btnAcceder.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btnAcceder.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        btnOlvidar.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        btnOlvidar.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btnOlvidar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        btnRegistro.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        btnRegistro.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btnRegistro.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        btnContinuar.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        btnContinuar.layer.borderWidth = 1
        btnContinuar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the performSegue a bit. But first.

1.) Remove the current segue (by clicking the connection in the storyboard and delete it)

2.) Drag a new segue (like you did when created your current one)

3.) Add the same identifier

4.) Fix your performSegue like:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "sinlogear", sender: self)
```

————

EDIT: A segue cannot be performed from `viewDidLoad()` because it’s too early. This function is runned before the storyboard is there. Consider using `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(){
 //perform the segue here
}
```

Comment: I have implemented all the points from your proposal, but with no success.

Comment: @mvasco Did you remove it as I suggested? And then added it again?

Comment: Yes, I did. I will try again, then I will close XCode, and check it again.

Comment: @mvasco Remove your if-statement and try to run the segue :)

Comment: I have put the segue outside the if statement and doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you provide full code? Either in a pastebin or if u edit the question and i’ll take a look :) @mvasco

Comment: I have created another segue to the same viewcontroller from a button action and it works, but the segue from the from controller to controller doesn't work

Comment: Where is your ”self.performSegue” located? Would you like to send the whole vc?

Comment: I found the solution. So you cannot have the segue inside your `viewDidLoad` because it’s too early for navigating. Put the segue code inside `viewDidAppear` @mvasco